# Is it possible to use one layout page for every view, including area views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have a layout page in `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and it works great for all normal views that get rendered. However, I created an area called "Demos" and in the `~/Areas/Demos/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file I pointed it to my original layout page.

This works just fine except some calls to `@Html.ActionLink()` are now being prefixed with the area name. So where `@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Blog")` would normally generate a link like "website.com/Blog/Index" on area views it generates "website.com/Demos/Blog/Index".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use areas open the Global.asax file and insert the following code into the Application_Start method

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

You can link within an area as you would in any MVC application but to generate a link to a different area, you must explicitly pass the target area name in the routeValues parameter for these methods.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Blog", new { area = "blog" }, null)
```

`null` parameter is required only because the ActionLink method overloads that have a routeValues parameter also have an htmlAttributes parameter but it is not required in order to be able to link between areas.

**UPDATE**

You can use `RouteLink()` instead of `ActionLink()`, to bypass the area registrations.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Blog", "MyRoute", new { action = "Index", controller = "Blog" })
```

The second parameter **("MyRoute")** is a route name registered in `Global.asax` so to use `RouteLink()` to link between different areas, you only need to specify the correct route name.

Comment: What about linking to a non-area? In my case I'm in an area trying to link out to a controller not in an area. Also, I already have RegisterAllAreas() being called in global.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Blog", new { area = "" }, null) What happens is the ActionLink method uses the CURRENT route data to build the links.